# Mocking S3 but not SQS from aws-sdk

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to use jest to mock only S3 from the aws-sdk, but not SQS for integration testing. How can I mock some parts of aws-sdk but not others?

Here's an example I'm trying:

```
jest.mock('aws-sdk')

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const { SQS } = jest.requireActual('aws-sdk')
const { transactions } = require('functions/transactions/handler')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const s3GetObject = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  createReadStream: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
    fs.createReadStream(path.resolve('__tests__/fixtures/data/transactions/example_with_lines.csv'))
  )
})

AWS.S3.mockImplementation(() => ({
  getObject: s3GetObject
}))

test('Integration Test: Send Large transaction file to QUEUE_TRANSACTION_URL SQS Queue', async () => {
  //const sqsSpy = jest.spyOn(SQS, 'sendMessageBatch')

  const testRecords = {
    Records: [{
      s3: {
        object: {
          key: 'testfile.csv'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

  await transactions(testRecords)
  expect(s3GetObject.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  expect(s3GetObject.mock.calls[0][0].Key).toBe('testFile.csv')
})
```

And I get back:

```
"sqs.sendMessageBatch is not a function",
"stack":
"TypeError: sqs.sendMessageBatch is not a function
    at sendMessageBatch (/app/app/services/aws/sendMessageToQueue.js:18:14)
    at sendBatch (/app/app/services/aws/sendMessageToQueue.js:26:25)
    at sendMessages (/app/app/services/handler.js:30:37)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at map (/app/app/services/handler.js:29:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/__tests__/integration/transaction.test.js:32:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jest you can use `jest.requireActual` to load the real module.

For example you can do

```js
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('aws-sdk'),
  S3: jest.fn() // make the stub do something
}))
```

Comment: Seems SQS can't get bound using requireActual. Edited Question with example

Comment: You don't want to import from jest.requireActual